# How to write begin and end statement at the top and bottom of algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

How can I write 'begin' and 'end' statement at the top and bottom the following code like this?[A sample pseuodcode with begin and end statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr6qU.png)

Besides using algorithm and algopseudocode package I can write Require and Ensure statement. Those are not properly aligned. Is there any way to align like the attached pic?

```
    % book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[
  % Replace twoside with oneside if you are printing your thesis on a single side
  % of the paper, or for viewing on screen.
  %oneside,
  twoside,
  11pt, a4paper,
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true,
  cleardoublepage=empty
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}



\begin{document}

\chapter{A Chapter}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Apriori algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \State $L_{1} \leftarrow Frequent 1-itemset $
    \State $k \leftarrow 2$
    \While{$L_{k-1} \neq \phi$}
    \State $Temp \leftarrow candidateItemSet (L_{k-1})$
    \State $C_{k} \leftarrow frequencyOfItemSet (Temp)$
    \State $L_{k} \leftarrow compareItemSetWithMinimumSupport (C_{k}, minsup) $
    \State $k \leftarrow k + 1$
    \EndWhile\\
    \Return L

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[Here is the online code](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/54bd39ded7cde44d3843b123)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` so that users willing to help will have a starting point without the need of additional setup.

Comment: I think this will just be a matter of making your own block, as in [`algorithmicx` section 4.2](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf). Something like `\algblock[name]{begin}{end}` with `\begin` and `\end` statements as needed.

Comment: @MikeRenfro `\begin` and `\end` are already defined... You can not use them.

Comment: Correct. My mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just define (in `algpseudocode` style)

```
\algdef{SE}{Begin}{End}{\textbf{begin}}{\textbf{end}}
```

and then use `\Begin` and `\End` as in the following example:

```
    % book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[
  % Replace twoside with oneside if you are printing your thesis on a single side
  % of the paper, or for viewing on screen.
  %oneside,
  twoside,
  11pt, a4paper,
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true,
  cleardoublepage=empty
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\algdef{SE}{Begin}{End}{\textbf{begin}}{\textbf{end}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Chapter} 
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Apriori algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Begin
    \State $L_{1} \leftarrow Frequent 1-itemset $
    \State $k \leftarrow 2$
    \While {$L_{k-1} \neq \phi$}
    \State $Temp \leftarrow candidateItemSet (L_{k-1})$
    \State $C_{k} \leftarrow frequencyOfItemSet (Temp)$
    \State $L_{k} \leftarrow compareItemSetWithMinimumSupport (C_{k}, minsup) $
    \State $k \leftarrow k + 1$
    \EndWhile
    \State \Return L
    \End
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Just a remark. You should not write

```
\EndWhile\\
\Return L
```

but

```
\EndWhile
\State \Return L
```

as in my example.

---

If you want a different indentation for `\Return` you can do the following.

Add

```
\def\BState{\State\hskip-.5em}
```

in the preamble and use `\BState` instead of `\State` in front of `\Return`.

MWE

```
    % book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[
  % Replace twoside with oneside if you are printing your thesis on a single side
  % of the paper, or for viewing on screen.
  %oneside,
  twoside,
  11pt, a4paper,
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true,
  cleardoublepage=empty
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\algdef{SE}{Begin}{End}{\textbf{begin}}{\textbf{end}}
\def\BState{\State\hskip-.5em}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Chapter} 
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Apriori algorithm}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Begin
    \State $L_{1} \leftarrow Frequent 1-itemset $
    \State $k \leftarrow 2$
    \While {$L_{k-1} \neq \phi$}
    \State $Temp \leftarrow candidateItemSet (L_{k-1})$
    \State $C_{k} \leftarrow frequencyOfItemSet (Temp)$
    \State $L_{k} \leftarrow compareItemSetWithMinimumSupport (C_{k}, minsup) $
    \State $k \leftarrow k + 1$
    \EndWhile
    \BState \Return L
    \End
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]